# BGI program aborts even after calling XInitThreads()?

Tags: c, bgi

I want to perform DDA line drawing algorithm using the [BGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Graphics_Interface). Sometimes when I run my program it works fine and sometimes it gets aborted with following error:

> [xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
>   [xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
>   [xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
>   a.out: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

I tried calling XInitThreads and some other solutions suggested previously for this question. But still it crashes most of the times.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

void drawLine(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    XInitThreads();
    //DDA Line Drawing Algorithm
    float deltaX, deltaY, step;
    int x = startX, y = endY;
    deltaX = (float)(endX - startX);
    deltaY = (float)(endY - startY);
    if(abs(deltaX) > abs(deltaY)) {
        step = deltaX;
    }
    else {
        step = deltaY;
    }
    putpixel(x, y,15);
    for(int i = 0; i < abs(step); i++) {
        x = (int)(x + deltaX/step + 0.5);
        y = (int)(y + deltaY/step + 0.5);
        putpixel(x, y,15);
        delay(100);
    }
}

int main() {
    XInitThreads();
    //Graphics Initialization.
    int gd = DETECT,gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, NULL);
    //Actual Code.
    int startX, startY, endX, endY, in = 0;
    printf("Starting point:\nX = ");
    scanf("%d", &startX);
    printf("\nY = ");
    scanf("%d", &startY);
    printf("Ending point:\nX = ");
    scanf("%d", &endX);
    printf("\nY = ");
    scanf("%d", &endY);
    delay(1000);
    drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY);
    //solution provided for same question asked previously.
    while(in == 0) {
        in = getchar();
    }
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which BGI implementation are you using?  [SDL_bgi](http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/)?  Why are you trying to mix BGI calls with raw X11 calls?

Comment: Yes. I am using SDL_bgi. I searched for solution and one of the solutions suggested to call XInitThreads() to solve this problem.

Comment: And when I take input from terminal (i.e. when I call initgraph in drawLine) the execution goes well but in the code given above it gets aborted most of the times.

Comment: Hrm, works fine (can enter line endpoints, line animates drawing) on my Debian Stretch amd64 system over VNC after removing the X11 stuff.